# c language function execution order in golang

Tags: go, goland

I am studying golang, but there is a part that I do not understand using c language.

In main, the c language function is executed for the second time, and the output is different depending on the IDE.
Why does this print out?

```
package main

//#include<stdio.h>
//void callC() {
// printf("Calling C code!\n");
//}
import "C"
import "fmt"


func main() {
    fmt.Println("A Go statement")
    C.callC()
    fmt.Println("Another Go statement")
}
```

-- **in GoLand (Template: go build with Run after build option)** --
output)
A Go statement
Another Go statement
Calling C code!

-- **in terminal**
$ go run hello.go
A Go statement
Calling C code!
Another Go statement

Comment: I've created this issue on the GoLand issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-6711

Comment: Is not that what I'm doing wrong? Is it likely to be a problem with GoLand? Thanks.

Comment: It's probably no problem with GoLand, it just flushes the stdout at a different time. when you add ` fflush( stdout ); ` after your printf call it should work like you think.

Comment: you are right. It works as expected when apply fflush. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C's `printf` is implemented in libc, using lower level system calls. libc has buffers for I/O to improve performance, and it decides when to flush these buffers (specifically the stdout stream which `printf` emits to is buffered).

Go has its own `printf` using lower level system calls, it doesn't uses C's `printf` or libc at all for this. Therefore its flushing decisions are separate from C's `printf`.

So there's not problem here, really. `printf` doesn't guarantee unbuffered output (you can use the error stream for that, if necessary, of flush explicitly), so there is no guaranteed ordering between the C and Go versions.

Comment: Eli, could you please explain why it works fine in shell? I was s/ltracing bash executing this program but cannot find any calls which disable buffering.

Comment: @neverov: there is no defined order between them, it depends on many factors of how the streams are handled